# How to set a date attribute to a current date in php using symfony 3

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, symfony

i have a problem setting a datetime attribute to the current date , if i force it to current timestamp i get a " Call to a member function format() on string" ERROR

```
**here are my getter and setter with some modifications**
public function getDateajout()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Tunis');
    $dateajout=date_default_timezone_get();
    return $this->dateajout;
}

public function setDateajout($dateajout)
{

    $this->dateajout =$dateajout;


}
```

Comment: set a time format like this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.it can be helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could return a \DateTime object as example:

```
/**
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */    
public function getDateajout()
{
    return new \DateTime('now', (new \DateTimeZone('Africa/Tunis'));
}
```

Hope this help